# SQL Server Function OR Procedure to cut records form table by parameters from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I have two tables i should make a comparing between those two tables, the first table have one column this column is the full `URL` and the other table have two columns first column is `URLCategory` and the other one is `the number` of how many `/` i should cut before in the other table column `URL`

the first table is

```
                          URL
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx
http://195.170.180.170/SADAD/PaymentNotificationService.asmx
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx
http://217.146.8.6/din.aspx?s=11575802&client=DynGate&p=10002926
http://195.170.180.170/SADAD/PaymentNotificationService.asmx
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx
http://195.170.180.170/SADAD/PaymentNotificationService.asmx
http://www.google.com/
```

the Second table which is hould compare with

```
  URL                              CUT_BEFORE
http://10.6.2.26                  3
http://217.146.8.6                1
http://195.170.180.170            2
```

I should compare between second table with first column to be like that

```
  URL                        
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices
http://195.170.180.170/SADAD
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices
http://217.146.8.6
http://195.170.180.170/SADAD
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices
http://195.170.180.170/SADAD
http://www.google.com/
```

What's the function script to do something like that in SQLServer

OR can we make it in Stored procedure with while loop because when i tried to execute the last function below i used this query

```
declare @table table
( main_url  NVARCHAR(MAX),URL NVARCHAR(MAX), count int)
insert @TABLE
select 
Main_URL,T2.Url,T2.[Count]
from 
(select 
URL as Main_URL,LEFT(URL1, CHARINDEX('/', URL1) - 1) as  URL1
from
(select URL,replace(stuff(URL1, 1,patindex('%://%', URL1 + '0'), ''),'//','') as URL1
from (select URL, convert(nvarchar(max),[Url]) Url1 from [dbo].[InternetUsage_nn] )T1)T)T1
left outer join [dbo].[InternetUsage_URL_List] T2
on T1.URL1=convert(nvarchar(max),T2.URL) where T2.URL is not null

select dbo.FindAbsolutePath('/',Main_url,count) from @Table
```

waiting for your answers

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following does what you requre, with the aid of a `Split` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@StringToSplit NVARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter NCHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(   
    SELECT  ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n.Number),
            Position = Number,
            Value = SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, Number, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringToSplit + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
    FROM    (   SELECT  TOP (LEN(@StringToSplit) + 1) Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id)
                FROM    sys.all_objects a
            ) n
    WHERE   SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @StringToSplit + @Delimiter, n.Number, 1) = @Delimiter
);
```

Once you have this function your code becomes relatively concise:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (URL VARCHAR(1000));
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (URL VARCHAR(1000), Cut_Before INT);
-- POPULATE TABLES HERE (NOT INCLUDED TO SAVE SPACE)

WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  FullURL = t.URL,
            BaseURLLength = LEN(ISNULL(t2.URL, t.URL)),
            Remainder = ISNULL(REPLACE(t.URL, t2.URL, ''), ''),
            Cut_Before = ISNULL(t2.Cut_Before, 1)
    FROM    @T AS t
            LEFT JOIN @T2 AS t2
                ON t.URL LIKE t2.URL + '/%'
)
SELECT  t.FullURL,
        Cut = SUBSTRING(t.FullURL, 1, BaseURLLength + LEN(s.Value) + s.Position - 1)
FROM    CTE t
        OUTER APPLY dbo.Split(t.Remainder, '/') AS s
WHERE   s.ID = t.Cut_Before;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dbf15/1)**

The premise is, the first part inside the CTE identifies the part URL for each full url by joining using `LIKE`. Using `http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx` as an example this will show the following:

```
FullURL:        http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx            
BaseURLLength:  16
Remainder:      /ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx
Cut_Before:     3
```

Where remainder is what is left of the full url after you have removed the part URL. The split function will then split the remainder into a new row for each of it's component parts:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Split('/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx', '/');
```

Will return:

```
ID  Position    Value
1   1   
2   2           ERP
3   6           HRServices
4   17          WorkflowService.asmx
```

This is then limited to only the row that matches the `Cut_Before` value. This row can then be used to establish the position to "Cut" the full URL (the starting position + the length of the value at that position).

Comment: Interesting solution. I'd suggest changing the `JOIN` condition in your CTE to `t.URL LIKE t2.URL + '/%'`, so that something like `http://1.2.3.4` in `t2` won't match something like `http://1.2.3.40/...` in `t`.

Comment: @JoeFarrell I am inclined to agree with you. I have made the change to the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

i modified my code. this code block will resolve your problem.

```
CREATE Function FindAbsolutePath(
 @TargetStr varchar(8000), 
 @SearchedStr varchar(8000), 
 @Occurrence int
)
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar(8000);

    if CHARINDEX('http://',@SearchedStr)>0 --fix http://
    BEGIN
        set @Occurrence=@Occurrence+2;
    END


    ;WITH Occurrences AS (
            SELECT 
            Number,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Number) AS Occurrence
            FROM master.dbo.spt_values
            WHERE 
            Number BETWEEN 1 
            AND LEN(@SearchedStr) 
            AND type='P'
            AND SUBSTRING(@SearchedStr,Number,LEN(@TargetStr))=@TargetStr
    )



    SELECT @Result= SUBSTRING(@SearchedStr,0,Number)
    FROM Occurrences
    WHERE Occurrence=@Occurrence 
    return @Result
END

--select dbo.FindAbsolutePath('/','http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx',3)
```

Comment: Also this function can use get n th index of spesific character in the string.

Comment: Thanks Bro. but when i tried to make it with full table it's give me an error i think we should add a loop in the function isn't it or i'm wrong :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1382335/cankaya07
I'd like to know how i can execute it between two tables to compare all of the records

Comment: i couldn't understand you. Compare all of records? What is your intend? this code should work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1382335/cankaya07  can we make it in stored procedure with while loop

Comment: i tried to use this to execute the function with logical table

`declare @table table( main_url  NVARCHAR(MAX),URL NVARCHAR(MAX), count int)
insert @TABLE select Main_URL,T2.Url,T2.[Count]
from (select URL as Main_URL,LEFT(URL1, CHARINDEX('/', URL1) - 1) as  URL1
from(select URL,replace(stuff(URL1, 1,patindex('%://%', URL1 + '0'), ''),'//','') as URL1
from (select URL, convert(nvarchar(max),[Url]) Url1 from [dbo].[InternetUsage_nn] )T1)T)T1
left outer join [dbo].[InternetUsage_URL_List] T2
on T1.URL1=convert(nvarchar(max),T2.URL)
select dbo.FindAbsolutePath('/',Main_url,count) from @Table`